# I want to join tables and sort them with Geocoder Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-geocoder

### What I want to solve

I want to combine the Area Model, Shop Model, and Account Model and get the results sorted in order of proximity from the location specified by the Geocoder Gem.

I want to list the results using `each` in a view.

However, I get a `no such column: distance` error as shown below.

In this case, no error will occur.

```rb
irb(main):043:0> Area.eager_load(:shop).near("tokyo")
  SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT areas.*, (69.09332411348201 * ABS(areas.latitude - 35.6828387) * 0.7071067811865475) + (59.836573914187355 * ABS(areas.longitude - 139.7594549) * 0.7071067811865475) AS distance, CASE WHEN (areas.latitude >= 35.6828387 AND areas.longitude >= 139.7594549) THEN  45.0 WHEN (areas.latitude <  35.6828387 AND areas.longitude >= 139.7594549) THEN 135.0 WHEN (areas.latitude <  35.6828387 AND areas.longitude <  139.7594549) THEN 225.0 WHEN (areas.latitude >= 35.6828387 AND areas.longitude <  139.7594549) THEN 315.0 END AS bearing, "areas"."id" AS t0_r0, "areas"."prefectures" AS t0_r1, "areas"."municipalities" AS t0_r2, "areas"."house_number" AS t0_r3, "areas"."building_name" AS t0_r4, "areas"."postal_code" AS t0_r5, "areas"."created_at" AS t0_r6, "areas"."updated_at" AS t0_r7, "areas"."latitude" AS t0_r8, "areas"."longitude" AS t0_r9, "shops"."id" AS t1_r0, "shops"."shop_name" AS t1_r1, "shops"."created_at" AS t1_r2, "shops"."updated_at" AS t1_r3, "shops"."shop_type_id" AS t1_r4, "shops"."station_id" AS t1_r5, "shops"."area_id" AS t1_r6 FROM "areas" LEFT OUTER JOIN "shops" ON "shops"."area_id" = "areas"."id" WHERE (areas.latitude BETWEEN 35.3933751337783 AND 35.972302266221696 AND areas.longitude BETWEEN 139.40308602609107 AND 140.11582377390894) ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
```

In this case, an error will occur

I want this to work.

```rb
irb(main):045:0> Area.eager_load(shop: :accounts).near("tokyo")
  SQL (3.3ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "areas"."id" FROM "areas" LEFT OUTER JOIN "shops" ON "shops"."area_id" = "areas"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."shop_id" = "shops"."id" WHERE (areas.latitude BETWEEN 35.3933751337783 AND 35.972302266221696 AND areas.longitude BETWEEN 139.40308602609107 AND 140.11582377390894) ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: distance)
```

### Environment

- Ruby 2.6.3
- Rails 6.0.3
- Geocoder Gem: <https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder>

#### Model association

```rb
# app/models/area

has_one :shop
```

```rb
# app/models/shop
belongs_to :shop_type
belongs_to :area
belongs_to :station

has_many :accounts
has_many :posts
```

```rb
# app/models/account

belongs_to :shop, optional: true
has_many :post
```

### Addition

I tried the below, but it failed.

```rb
irb(main):001:0> Area.near("tokyo").eager_load(shop: :accounts)
   (0.9ms)  SELECT sqlite_version(*)
  SQL (0.4ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "areas"."id" FROM "areas" LEFT OUTER JOIN "shops" ON "shops"."area_id" = "areas"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."shop_id" = "shops"."id" WHERE (areas.latitude BETWEEN 35.3933751337783 AND 35.972302266221696 AND areas.longitude BETWEEN 139.40308602609107 AND 140.11582377390894) ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: distance)

irb(main):002:0> Area.near("tokyo").eager_load(shop: :accounts)
  SQL (0.3ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "areas"."id" FROM "areas" LEFT OUTER JOIN "shops" ON "shops"."area_id" = "areas"."id" LEFT OUTER JOIN "accounts" ON "accounts"."shop_id" = "shops"."id" WHERE (areas.latitude BETWEEN 35.3933751337783 AND 35.972302266221696 AND areas.longitude BETWEEN 139.40308602609107 AND 140.11582377390894) ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 11]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: distance)
irb(main):003:0>
```

Answer (score 0):

The documentation mentions,

> You cannot use the near scope with another scope that provides an
> includes option because the SELECT clause generated by near will
> overwrite it (or vice versa).
>
> Instead of using includes to reduce the number of database queries,
> try using joins with either the :select option or a call to preload.
> For example:

So, maybe try `Area.near("tokyo").eager_load(shop: :accounts)` or `Area.near("tokyo").joins(shop: :accounts)` and see if that works?

Comment: Thank you, I read the document again. However, the code failed.
I added the execution result to the question.